# Can I develop apps for iOS on Windows using Kotlin?

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to build an app for iOS on Windows. I know how to develop apps for iOS on windows using Objective-C but I would like to know how I can build apps for iOS on windows using Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

I used these articles, which gave me a good overview about the possibilities for Kotlin and iOS (and yes it is possible)

[multiplatform native development in kotlin](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/multiplatform-native-development-in-kotlin-now-with-ios-a8546f436eec)

and this one

[targeting kotlin for android and ios](https://proandroiddev.com/targeting-kotlin-for-both-android-and-ios-dec5b967006a)

Comment: ok sir Thank you i will read this and tell u after read @Vario

Comment: can you explain where should i write code for ios ?

Comment: this is basically not asked in the question, but you can use any editor. Maybe you try IntelliJ or see this link if you wanna try it with XCode https://ericasadun.com/2017/05/30/erica-knows-nothing-about-kotlin-installing-and-using-kotlin-from-xcode/

Comment: @GouravManuja did you need more help or are you fine with this question?

Comment: yeah sir i need more help @Vario

Comment: @GouravManuja please refer to the points related to this question where you need more help, or ask a new question and mark this as accepted, if it is not related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write but not run code

based on documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-setup.html#install-the-necessary-tools)

[image: cannot run kotlin]